# Переадресация по таймеру

Tags: php, html, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно сделать таймер, который по истечению времени переносит пользователя на другую страницу. Пример.

Бой одного пользователя с другим. Один использует одну атаку, другой - другую атаку. Но через некоторое время один из них понял, что если продолжать битву, он проиграет. Время боя 5 минут. Так тот пользователь ждет эти 5 минут, их выкидывает с боя и никому не добавили, не отняли очки. Мне нужно создать таймер, который по истечению времени выкинет пользователя, который мухлевал на страницу проигрыша, а который ждал, пока походит противник, - на страницу выигрыша.

Можно ли сделать этот таймер так?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
    <title>тест</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <script>
        var limit = 5; // в секундах
        function processTimer() {
            if (limit > 0) {
                setTimeout("processTimer()", 1000);
                limit--;
            } else {
                // здесь действия после завершения таймера
                //..
            }
            var limit_div = parseInt(limit / 60); // минуты
            var limit_mod = limit - limit_div * 60; // секунды
            // строка с оставшимся временем
            limit_str = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            if (limit_div < 10) limit_str = limit_str + "0";
            limit_str = limit_str + limit_div + ":";
            if (limit_mod < 10) limit_str = limit_str + "0";
            limit_str = limit_str + limit_mod + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            // вывод времени
            el_timer = document.getElementById("timer");
            if (el_timer) el_timer.innerHTML = limit_str;
        }
        processTimer();
    </script>
</body>
```

Как сделать пере адресацию на страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обратили внимание на то что setTimeout находится внутри функции `processTimer`, и функция `processTimer` не вызовется используя только `processTimer();` на последней строке скрипта?

Следовательно setTimeout нужно вынести за пределы функции processTimer и радоваться!

Answer (score 1):

```
location.href=URL;
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую!
хотя похожее пробовал!

Comment: не работает!

Comment: а что говорит?

Comment: ничего не показывает! время не идет! попробуте сделайте Вы и скиньте исходник, я посмотрю!

Comment: Пфф....за вас тут никто работать не будет, мы помогаем, а не делаем работу за кого то, это Вам не фриланс.ру

Answer (score 1):

> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2000;url=http://example.com/">;

content="время(в ссекундах);url=ссылка"